# Java - working with different cmd charsets

Tags: java, cmd, character-encoding, hebrew

I want to read a file path from the user in java console application,
some of the file path may contain some Hebrew characters.

how can i read the input from the command line when i don't know the encoding charset?

I have been spending some time on the web and didn't succeed to find any relevant solution that will be dynamic for every platform.

*
[Screen shot when running in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27OgM.png)

Comment: If by "command line" you mean the arguments to the `main()` method, that is already converted to Java String....

Comment: CMD is a Unicode application. It reads the command line from its attached console using the wide-character function `ReadConsoleW` and executes it by calling either `CreateProcessW` or `ShellExecuteExW`. Legacy codepages are only used if the command line is read from a file such as a batch file, in which case it uses the current console codepage (or ANSI if there's no attached console), which can be set via chcp.com to match the encoding of the batch file.

Comment: 1. Usagi Miyamoto - No i dont mean main arg's i mean Windows Command Prompt that actualy get the paramaters from the user.

2.eryksun - i didn't get the button line from you, 
how can i solve my problem that i'm don't getting the right input from console, even if you right and the console don't using code pages that must be a a reason why i'm don't getting the right  input as in the IDE terminal that use UTF-8 for IO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows you need to check the terminal encoding before to make sure that its encoding supports hebrew.

To do this just type chcp in the console

as output you should see chcp 28598

if you see diffrent number type chcp 28598

Now your console encoding is set to hebrew and you should be able to write the path in hebrew without getting any exception.